# XSLT 2.0 Type checking: I get error "Unknown type xsl:string"

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am working on a complex XSLT transformation. I am using XSLT 2.0. This page, https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-schemaawarexslt/index.html, explains that you can add type checking to your templates. This does not work with me.

Here is my example XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="columnWidths"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="row">
      <xsl:with-param name="columnWidths" select="$columnWidths"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:param name="columnWidths"/>
    <line>
      <xsl:variable name="first">
        <xsl:value-of select="field[position() = 1]/text()"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="second">
        <xsl:call-template name="padString">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="field[position() = 2]/text()"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="length" select="subsequence($columnWidths, 2, 1)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="align" select="'left'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="third">
        <xsl:call-template name="padString">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="field[position() = 3]/text()"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="length" select="subsequence($columnWidths, 3, 1)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="align" select="'right'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(($first, $second, $third), ' ')"/>
    </line>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="padString">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:param name="length"/>
    <xsl:param name="align"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($value) &gt;= number($length)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="appended">
          <xsl:call-template name="generalAppend">
            <xsl:with-param name="in" select="$value"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:call-template name="padString">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$appended/append/*[local-name()=$align]/text()"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="align" select="$align"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="generalAppend">
    <xsl:param name="in" as="xsl:string"/>
    <append>
      <left><xsl:value-of select="concat($in, ' ')"/></left>
      <right><xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', $in)"/></right>
    </append>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XSLT processor gives the following error:

> line [57] column [43]: Unknown type xsl:string

This line reads:

```
<xsl:param name="in" as="xsl:string"/>
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: That article you link to does not use `xsl:string`, it seems, it uses `xs:string`.

Comment: I agree. I missed the difference when I read it. If you wrote that article, can you then mention the namespaces referenced by "xs" and "xsl" explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

You try to get the type "string" from the wrong namespace. The type "string" lives in the XML Schema namespace which differs from the XSLT namespace. Here is the correct version of the above XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:param name="columnWidths"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="row">
      <xsl:with-param name="columnWidths" select="$columnWidths"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:param name="columnWidths"/>
    <line>
      <xsl:variable name="first">
        <xsl:value-of select="field[position() = 1]/text()"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="second">
        <xsl:call-template name="padString">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="field[position() = 2]/text()"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="length" select="subsequence($columnWidths, 2, 1)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="align" select="'left'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="third">
        <xsl:call-template name="padString">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="field[position() = 3]/text()"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="length" select="subsequence($columnWidths, 3, 1)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="align" select="'right'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(($first, $second, $third), ' ')"/>
    </line>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="padString">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:param name="length"/>
    <xsl:param name="align"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($value) &gt;= number($length)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="appended">
          <xsl:call-template name="generalAppend">
            <xsl:with-param name="in" select="$value"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:call-template name="padString">
          <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$appended/append/*[local-name()=$align]/text()"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="align" select="$align"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="generalAppend">
    <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:string"/>
    <append>
      <left><xsl:value-of select="concat($in, ' ')"/></left>
      <right><xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', $in)"/></right>
    </append>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A namespace prefix "xs" has been introduced for the XML Schema namespace. The definition of the parameter type then references this prefix:

`<xsl:param name="in" as="xs:string"/>`